# htaccess RewriteRule 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Let's say I had this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^page(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`page/` and onwards (`page/error/` etc) gives me a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to make last slash and other URI components optional:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Now when I use a trailing slash for just `page/` it gives me the server error, again.

Comment: If URI is just `/page` then error is empty so you may not need to right that to `/page.php?error=`

Comment: Yes, the whole /error/page is optional. Error is just to say there's an error, that does nothing. The part after /error/ is the part where it points out. e.g. `page/error/something` would call `page.php?error=something`

Comment: That worked, but now, when I go to `/page` or `/page/` it gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: I've updated the original post to what's happening now, but it's still not working.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't include my suggested `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: It's still doing the same even when I add it.

Comment: `This webpage has a redirect loop` even when going to `page`

Comment: I have tested above rules and `/page` is going to `/page.php`

Comment: If I go to `page.php` it loads fine, removing that `.php` makes it all fail and has a loop.

Comment: As I wrote with exactly this code in my .htaccess `/page loads /page.php` Your problem could be due to some code in your page.php.

Comment: You're right, sorry. It was reaching the `default:` in my php code. Thank you!